# Python zipfile does not unzip folders for windows zip archive

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, archive, python-zipfile

I have a zip file which was created on `Windows` machine using this tool `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` (this zip archive contains many files and folders). I have a python code that runs on `Linux` machine (raspberry pi to be exact) which has to unzip the archive and create all the necessary folders and files. I'm using `Python 3.5.0` and `zipfile` library, this is a sample code:

```
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("MyArchive.zip","r")
zip.extractall()
zip.close()
```

Now when I run this code instead of getting a nice unzipped directory tree, I get all the files in root directory with weird names like `Folder1\Folder2\MyFile.txt`.

My assumption is that since zip archive was created on Windows and directory separator on windows is `\` whereas on Linux it is `/`, python `zipfile` library treats `\` as part of a file name instead of directory separator. Also note that when I'm extracting this archive manually (not through python code) all the folder are created as expected, so it seems that this is definitely a problem of `zipfile` library. Another note is that for zip archives that where created with a different tool (not `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`) it works OK using the same python code.

Any insight on what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Zip files store everything in the root. The hierarchy is virtually created through the slashes in the file names.

Comment: Show how you extract the archive manually

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is all the python code. Or what code are you asking about?

Comment: @MadPhysicist very simple `sudo unzip MyArchive.zip` and this works fine.

Comment: Try this: `from os import path; path.altsep = '\\'` anywhere before you call `extractall`.

Comment: If it works, I'll post an answer

Comment: Thanks! It helped, you can post it I will put it as the answer if you want.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good call. I did not notice the line that follows the line I pointed out in my answer makes use of `os.path.altsep` for replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that while Windows recognizes both `\` (`path.sep`) and `/` (`path.altsep`) as path separators, Linux only recognizes `/` (`path.sep`).

As [@blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52091287/2988730) shows, the existing implementation of `ZipFile` always ensures that `path.sep` and `/` are considered valid separator characters. That means that on Linux, `\` is treated as a literal part of the file name. To change that, you can set `os.altsep` to `\`, since it gets checked if it's not None or empty.

If you go down the road of modifying `ZipFile` itself, like the other answer suggests, just add a line to blindly change `\` to `path.sep`, since `/` is always changed already anyway. That way, `/`, `\`and possibly `path.altsep` will all be converted to `path.sep`. This is what the command line tool appears to be doing.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a bug of the [`zipfile` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py), where it has the following line in `ZipFile._extract_member()` to blindly replace `'/'` in the file names with the OS-specific path separator, when it should also look for `'\\'`:

```
arcname = member.filename.replace('/', os.path.sep)
```

You can fix this by overriding `ZipFile._extract_member()` with a version that's directly copied from the source code but with the above line corrected:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo
import shutil
import os
def _extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd):
    """Extract the ZipInfo object 'member' to a physical
       file on the path targetpath.
    """
    if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
        member = self.getinfo(member)

    if os.path.sep == '/':
        arcname = member.filename.replace('\\', os.path.sep)
    else:
        arcname = member.filename.replace('/', os.path.sep)

    if os.path.altsep:
        arcname = arcname.replace(os.path.altsep, os.path.sep)
    # interpret absolute pathname as relative, remove drive letter or
    # UNC path, redundant separators, "." and ".." components.
    arcname = os.path.splitdrive(arcname)[1]
    invalid_path_parts = ('', os.path.curdir, os.path.pardir)
    arcname = os.path.sep.join(x for x in arcname.split(os.path.sep)
                               if x not in invalid_path_parts)
    if os.path.sep == '\\':
        # filter illegal characters on Windows
        arcname = self._sanitize_windows_name(arcname, os.path.sep)

    targetpath = os.path.join(targetpath, arcname)
    targetpath = os.path.normpath(targetpath)

    # Create all upper directories if necessary.
    upperdirs = os.path.dirname(targetpath)
    if upperdirs and not os.path.exists(upperdirs):
        os.makedirs(upperdirs)

    if member.is_dir():
        if not os.path.isdir(targetpath):
            os.mkdir(targetpath)
        return targetpath

    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
            open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

    return targetpath
ZipFile._extract_member = _extract_member
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, given that the method already does that.

Comment: Fixed with a conditional statement instead.

Comment: Keeping slash actually makes sense. The real solution would be to pass in altsep to the function.